# UIButton that's created programmatically crashing when method called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a rootViewController and have a UIButton that's created programmatically. I want this UIButton to display another view controller. For some reason it crashes with the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TutorialViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

here's the code that creates an Info UIButton. this code is in the loadView method:

```
 // Create a Button to get Help          
 UIButton *helpButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark ] ;
 CGRect buttonRect = helpButton.frame;

 // CALCulate the bottom right corner
 buttonRect.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width - buttonRect.size.width - 8;
 buttonRect.origin.y = buttonRect.size.height - 8; 
 [helpButton setFrame:buttonRect];

 [helpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doHelp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [self.view addSubview:helpButton];

}
```

Here's the action to transisition to another view controller:

```
- (IBAction)doHelp:(id)sender{
 NSLog(@"help button pressed");

 TutorialViewController *sampleView = [[[TutorialViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
 [sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
 [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
}
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you initializing the view controller with "init" instead of "initWithNibName:bundle:" ?

Comment: init should be okay, worst case the viewController doesn't have a view and appears black. Maybe he calls `initWithNibName:bundle:` from this init method. I do this from time to time.

Comment: OK, so it was not a crash but a build failure, right? that was confusing me in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in your Target settings, on Build Phases under Compile Sources list that you have TutorialViewController.m file in the list.

Comment: Or select TutorialViewController.m and check "Target Membership" in the right side bar .

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Nifty ! didn't know about that :)

Comment: you were right! I copied the TutorialViewController files into the project. something must have gone wrong during the copy... thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

adig is probably right.

Also, that technically isn't a "crash."  It "fails to build, with this linker error."  You can tell that it's a linker error because it said, "ld returned 1 exit status".  ld is the linker.

Under the covers, XCode compiles and links your code before running it.  If it fails during compilation or linking, it's a "build failure," not a "crash."  A crash is when the application built, but then suddenly stopped at run time.  One common cause of this is accessing a nil pointer.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `(IBAction)doHelp:(id)sender` you must write `(void)doHelp`....try this:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you #importing the .h file, not the .m file?

The problem is not with your UIButton, the problem is the TutorialViewController class is not being compiled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

very basic but somtime we may miss it :) 
have you declared same method in .h file?

Answer (score -1):

I think instead of `(IBAction)`, you must write `(void)`

Comment: No IBAction is defined as void:
#define IBAction void

Comment: But the button is created not by IB...so I think should not we write (void) instead (IBOutlet)??

Comment: @hanumanDev: Remove (id)sender from ur method...I think this is the final solution...

Comment: @Goti Your answer is not proper. It is a wrong concept to use `(void)` instead  of `(IBAction)` in case of actions associated to UI elements